How to send Wi-Fi Credentials to ESP32 using hotspot in flutter app
I have an iOT project.
Where I need to send home wifi credentials on iOT device.
Firstly, I have to connect the mobile app to the iOT device hotspot. Then send wifi credentials to the iOT device without internet. then the device automatically connects to WiFi.
I already try lots of package but not been able to achieve this task.
I tried Following package
wifi_iot
flutter_iot_wifi
flutter_esp_ble_prov
esp_provisioning_ble
esp_provisioning_softap
Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

1st method

Just create one local web server on the iOT device (ESP32) side.
Create one GET request on the local server (ex : /get_credantials).
Connect your smartphone to esp32 and send credentials via above GET request.

Example for reference: Link
2nd method

Create BLE Server on esp side and start advertising it
Create characteristic on same server with write/read access to get wifi credantials via BLE
Connect to that server via smartphone and send data through that characteristic.

Example for reference: Link

Thanks for your help can we connect and you help me i will take only 5 mint of yours
